# How do I show multiple child nodes of an xml without having to list each in my code?

Tags: python, pandas, xml, export-to-csv

I am new to python and want to shorten the lines of code/ reduce the effort to have all available child nodes listed:

My file.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<HEADER>
    <PRODUCT_DETAILS>
        <DESCRIPTION_SHORT>green cat w short hair</DESCRIPTION_SHORT>
        <DESCRIPTION_LONG>green cat w short hair and unlimited zoomies</DESCRIPTION_LONG>
        <BUYER_PID type="supplier_specific">100000000</BUYER_PID>
    </PRODUCT_DETAILS>
    <PRODUCT_FEATURES>
        <FEATURE>
            <FNAME>Hair</FNAME>
            <FVALUE>medium</FVALUE>
        </FEATURE>
        <FEATURE>
            <FNAME>Colour</FNAME>
            <FVALUE>green</FVALUE>
        </FEATURE>
        <FEATURE>
            <FNAME>Legs</FNAME>
            <FVALUE>14</FVALUE>
        </FEATURE>
    </PRODUCT_FEATURES>
</HEADER>
```

My code looks like this:

```
from lxml import etree as et
import pandas as pd

xml_data = et.parse('file.xml')
products = xml_data.xpath('//HEADER')

headers=[elem.tag for elem in xml_data.xpath('//HEADER[1]//PRODUCT_DETAILS//*')]
headers.extend(xml_data.xpath('//HEADER[1]//FNAME/text()'))

rows = []

for product in products:

    row = [product.xpath(f'.//{headers[0]}/text()')[0],product.xpath(f'.//{headers[1]}/text()')[0],product.xpath(f'.//{headers[2]}/text()')[0]]
    
    f_values = product.xpath('.//FVALUE/text()')
    row.extend(f_values)    
    rows.append(row)

df = pd.ataFrame(rows,columns=headers)

df
# df.to_csv("File_Export_V1.csv", index=False)
```

Specifically, I am talking about this part:

```
row = [product.xpath(f'.//{headers[0]}/text()')[0],product.xpath(f'.//{headers[1]}/text()')[0],product.xpath(f'.//{headers[2]}/text()')[0]]
```

When more and more child nodes are added to my xml I currently expand the code by:

```
,product.xpath(f'.//{headers[3]}/text()')[0],product.xpath(f'.//{headers[4]}/text()')[0],...]
```

Surely there must be a simpler way to not have to check the number of child nodes beforehand and simply show all available child nodes(?). This is my output btw:

```
    DESCRIPTION_SHORT       DESCRIPTION_LONG                                BUYER_PID   Hair    Colour  Legs
0   green cat w short hair  green cat w short hair and unlimited zoomies    100000000   medium  green   14
```

**Thank you for any help!
~ C**

Comment: As I mentioned to you, although it's possible to do what you want here using lxml, it's **much** simpler to do if you can use xpath>1.0 using elemenpath. Can you install elemenpath on your system?

Comment: Done. Any good resources/ previous questions you can point me to? :)

Comment: See below. If that doesn't work, we can go back to xpath 1.0...

Answer (score 0):

Try this one on your actual data:

```
from elementpath import select

expression1 = '//HEADER[1]/string-join((./PRODUCT_DETAILS//*/name(),./PRODUCT_FEATURES//FNAME),",")'
expression2 = '//HEADER/string-join((./PRODUCT_DETAILS//*,./PRODUCT_FEATURES//FVALUE),",")'

headers = [h.split(',') for h in select(xml_data, expression1 )]
rows= [r.split(',') for r in select(xml_data, expression2)]
pd.DataFrame(rows,columns=headers)
```

and see if it works.

Comment: Well, elementpath is installed but I get the reportMissingImports. Any pointers on this?

Comment: @Charles That's not really my area; I vaguely remember it may have to do with VSCode settings (if you are working with VS Code) or with virtual environments? Assuming the module actually installed correctly, you should try to fix your setup first before attempting to answer this particular question.